# How to extract just numeric value with REGEXP_EXTRACT in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, extract

I am trying to extract just the numbers from a particular column in BigQuery.
The fields concerned have this format: value = "Livraison_21J|Relais_19J" or "RELAIS_15 DAY"
I am trying to extract the number of days for each value preceeded by the keyword "Relais".
The days range from 1 to 100.

I used this to do so:

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(delivery, r"RELAIS_([0-9]+J)") as string) as relayDay
FROM TABLE
```

I want to be able to extract just the number of days regardless of the the string that comes after the numbers, be it "J" or "DAY".

Sample data :

```
RETRAIT_2H|LIVRAISON_5J|RELAIS_5J    |     5J

LIVRAISON_21J|RELAIS_19J             |     19J

LIVRAISON_21J|RELAIS_19J             |     19J

RETRAIT_2H|LIVRAISON_3J|RELAIS_3J    |     3J
```

Comment: please provide sample data that should be matched

Comment: As in the first number, do you mean `19`? The second number > `15` isn't followed by a capital J. Meaning your pattern is wrong.

Comment: Try `SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(delivery, r'[^0-9|]+',''), '|')`

Comment: added sample data

Comment: What does `|` in that sample data mean?  Expected result? So you want a single value, before the last `J` or `DAY`? Then try `REGEXP_EXTRACT(delivery, r"(?:.*\D)?(\d+)\s*(?:J|DAY)")`

Comment: Match to the last underscore and then extract the number that follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(delivery, r"(?:.*\D)?(\d+)\s*(?:J|DAY)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4S8UxA/2)

**Details**

- `(?:.*\D)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 0+ chars other than line break chsrs as many as possible and then a non-digit char (this pattern is required to advance the index to the location right before the last sequence of digits, not the last digit)
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (just what the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` returns): one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:J|DAY)` - `J` or `DAY` substrings.